# Why does "alias python=/usr/local/bin/python3.7" keep getting appended to my .zshrc every time I open up a homebrew managed version of Anaconda?

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh, homebrew, datascience-anaconda

I run a fairly stock .zshrc configuration. Stock meaning only a couple of aliases and a theme. But every time I open my .zshrc, I see several appended lines that all say this:

```
"alias python=/usr/local/bin/python3.7"
```

Here is the teminal output from during the launch:

```
    To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
        file:///Users/alexrook/Library/Jupyter/runtime/nbserver-22716-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://localhost:8890/?token=d9124fbeae0ec69f3bad4e31cfd0b22d568a08c4ef053227
     or http://127.0.0.1:8890/?token=d9124fbeae0ec69f3bad4e31cfd0b22d568a08c4ef053227
[E 20:14:12.598 NotebookApp] Could not open static file ''
[W 20:14:12.726 NotebookApp] 404 GET /static/components/react/react-dom.production.min.js (::1) 13.87ms referer=http://localhost:8890/tree?token=d9124fbeae0ec69f3bad4e31cfd0b22d568a08c4ef053227
[W 20:14:12.861 NotebookApp] 404 GET /static/components/react/react-dom.production.min.js (::1) 1.45ms referer=http://localhost:8890/tree?token=d9124fbeae0ec69f3bad4e31cfd0b22d568a08c4ef053227
```

Answer (score 1):

You may have written something like this in your `.zshrc`, or other ZSH init files.

```bsh
echo "alias python=/usr/local/bin/python3.7" >> ~/.zshrc
```

I've seen another zsh/bash newbie did similar silly thing, which resulted in a 240MB size '.zshrc'.

The `echo` command should run in the shell interactive once, but not be put in the conf `.zshrc`. Otherwise, it makes the `.zshrc` modify itself every time on shell startup.

Please check you ZSH init files for similar `echo` command.

1. `/etc/zshenv`
2. `~/.zshenv`
3. login mode:

   1. `/etc/zprofile`
   2. `~/.zprofile`
4. interactive:

   1. `/etc/zshrc`
   2. `~/.zshrc`
5. login mode:

   1. `/etc/zlogin`
   2. `~/.zlogin`